# xm parser error python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from xml.dom import minidom

user_input = raw_input("Enter the path of your file: ")
#f = open(user_input,'r+')
#str(f)
apktool = "/usr/share/apktool/apktool.jar"
os.system(apktool + " d " +  user_input)
base = os.path.basename(user_input)
a = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
#b = os.path.dirname(user_input)
d = os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
#print d
#print a
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0])):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.startswith('AndroidManifest'):
            pth = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,filename))
            #print pth
dom1 = minidom.parse(pth)
activity = dom1.getElementsByTagName("intent-filter")
for b in activity:
    activity= b.parentNode.getAttribute("android:name")
    export= b.parentNode.getAttribute("android:exported")
    if (export=='false'):
        print activity , "Exported but not exploitable"
    else:
        print activity , "Not Protected"
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\archie\Androidtestsuite\apktool\decompile.py", line 22, in <module>
    dom1 = minidom.parse(pth)
NameError: name 'pth' is not defined
```

using python 2.7. This code works fine in Ubuntu, however it gives error in windows.Is it the xml parser issue or am I missing something.

Comment: It looks like your indentation is broken - isn't `dom1 = minidom.parse(pth)` supposed to be at the same level as `pth = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,filename))`? Please correct it - and you should use 4 spaces indents in Python.

Comment: I tried doing that also but it still gives the same error

Comment: What does `os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0]))` return? It looks like the 3rd element (`files`) is the empty list, so it doesn't enter the `for` loop and therefore `pth` is not initialized (and declared).

Comment: os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.path.splitext(base)[0])) gives the absolute path of the file that we give as user_input